# How to add a package from Swift Package Manager by build configuration? (workaround)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift-package-manager

Is there any workaround to add a package from Swift Package Manager like in Cocoapods:

```
pod 'PonyDebugger', :configurations => ['Debug', 'Beta']
pod 'PonyDebugger', :configuration => 'Debug'
```

I know there is a proposed solution (https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0273-swiftpm-conditional-target-dependencies.md#proposed-solution) but it is not fully implemented and cannot be used.

My scenario: I have the same framework in two versions and one of them should be used in development and another should be used in release. What can I do to differentiate them according to my build configurations? Is the unique solution using different targets?